# Which library for receiving email, performing actions server side

Tags: email

I would like to implement an email receiving feature similar to the one found at asana.com:
http://asana.com/guide/tags-email/email-incoming

Users can send email to a designated address, and the system will perform actions based on recipient and message contents.

Any recommendations for libraries that handle this?

I see openpop.net, but i wonder if this technology would have a delay since by nature pop doesn't receive mail on its own, you must initiate the request.

Anyway, hoping to get the scoop on this technology from the experts here. Preferably, an answer would direct me to both a library and some tutorial/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this on a Linux box, it's fairly straight-forward to set it up such that incoming emails are piped directly to a script - be it PHP, PERL, etc.  See http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/ for an excellent article.